# How can image meta data stored in a SQL-server database be utilized by SEO?

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, image, seo

I've got a .NET (VB) web project with image meta data such as alt text stored in a SQL database which is retrieved at page load and matched with corresponding images stored in a file on the web server.
Viewing the HTML with Google page source does show the images matched with their alt text.

None of these images appear in any web search. Is there anything I can add/change to allow these images to be included in a search engine?

If it helps, all other images with alt text and (image file location) stored in resource files (it's a multi-language site) do appear in image search engines.

Thanks!

Comment: Nothing has anything to do with SQL here. All is about HTML. Make sure you emit the correct HTML for google to find it, have enough reputation etc., get cralwed and they WIL show up.

Comment: Whoops. You're absolutely right. I got tunnel vision and was convinced it was something else besides the HTML. I had omitted `'AlternateText='<%# Eval("imgDescription") %>'` from the asp:image command. Thanks.

Comment: It wasn't that. Other images appear high up in a Google search within a day or two. The images here (with similar alt text etc) never, ever appear. It's a pain as I only really wanted to add new images by uploading them to the web-server and adding the relevant text row on the database and not by re-writing HTML each time. Has anyone else seen this?